# Is it possible to disable "Display hidden-mode notification tooltip" programmatically on UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, alm

I'm trying to run some automation tests in my application but the UFT Hidden-mode notification tooltip is coming in front of the objects in the screen, preventing my tests to run.
I know I can un-check the option "Display hidden-mode notification tooltip" in Remote Agent Settings to fix this issue and it works fine on my machine after I do this, but these tests are executed in other machines, by other users in my company, and it would be a real effort to tell each and everyone of them to change this setting on their machine. 
Is it a way to disable this checkbox programmaticaly instead?

**EDIT:**
Here is a little more detail on where this is affecting me: 
I'm testing a Web application and in some of my test cases I need to download a file from this application. I do that by clicking on "Save As" in the context menu which is displayed on a notification bar at the bottom of the browser.
Following is the portion of code to perform such operation:

```
Dim brwBottom
Set brwBottom = Browser("brw_Bottom_Save_As")

If brwBottom.WinObject("wo_Notification").WinButton("wb_Selector").Exist Then
    brwBottom.WinObject("wo_Notification").WinButton("wb_Selector").Click
    brwBottom.WinMenu("wm_Selector").Select "Save As"
End If
```

This works fine on my machine because UFT notification is not being displayed, but in other machines where the UFT Notification **is** displayed, it overlaps the menu and my script is unable to select the "Save As" option. So, in case it is not possible to programmatically close this notification at runtime, is there any alternative solution to click on the "Save As" button, even with this notification overlapping it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to identify the UFT Notification tooltip and close it. With this, there is no more objects in front of the button I need to click and my script can be executed successfully. 
Following is the code used. I'm not marking this as the acceptable answer yet because I am still waiting for my team to accept the solution, but this works.

```
Dim brwBottom
Set brwBottom = Browser("brw_Bottom_Save_As")

' To close UFT Notification Tooltip, if exists
If Window("regexpwndtitle:=NotificationWindow").Exist(2) Then
    If InStr(Window("regexpwndtitle:=NotificationWindow").GetROProperty("nativeclass"),"UFTRemoteAgent") > 0 Then
        Window("regexpwndtitle:=NotificationWindow").Close
    End If
End If

If brwBottom.WinObject("wo_Notification").WinButton("wb_Selector").Exist Then
    brwBottom.WinObject("wo_Notification").WinButton("wb_Selector").Click
    brwBottom.WinMenu("wm_Selector").Select "Save As"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Marked as favorite in case future need. :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer if that has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Create UFT GUI test and include these three lines:

```
extern.Declare micLong, "WritePrivateProfileString", "kernel32.dll", "WritePrivateProfileString", micString, micString, micString, micString
extern.WritePrivateProfileString "RemoteAgent", "ShowBallon", "0", Environment("ProductDir") + "\bin\mic.ini"
systemutil.CloseProcessByName "UFTRemoteAgent.exe"
```

From ALM, run it on all your UFT machines.

**Notes:**

1. This will switch the flag that controls such tooltip to be off, so next time Remote Agent launches will read it and won't display the tooltip anymore.
2. The third line will kill UFT's remote agent for GUI testing which is in charge of the communication between UFT and ALM Client and this will cause an error in ALM's Automatic Runner (The RPC server is unavailable)... just ignore it. We need to kill it so it is re-launched next time we try to run a test from ALM (as mentioned above, new value for tooltip will be read)

**EDIT:**

I just found something interesting: this flag is actually saved in two locations:

1. mic.ini
2. RemoteAgentGUISettings.xml

but the one that actually makes the change effective is RemoteAgentGUISettings.xml (it seems they're switching from .ini files to .xml... which makes sense). In this case, the code will change a little, but the idea is the same:

```
filePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%") + "\Hewlett-Packard\UFT\Persistence\Dialogs\RemoteAgentGUISettings.xml"
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.load filePath
Set nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//SettingsViewModel/IsShowBalloon")
nNode.text = "false"
strResult = xmldoc.save(filePath)
systemutil.CloseProcessByName "UFTRemoteAgent.exe"
```

This time I made sure it works ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this is not very practical, since I would still need to ask each tester to run this on their machines and also remember to run it on server machines, which would be also the same as ask them to disable such notification. This would become a pre-requirement to execute only my testsets. For that matter, my current approach is still preferable, since it kills the notification only on the point that it is affecting the execution

Comment: No problem. It is just another alternative. The benefit is that this is one time run for the setting to be applied (no footprint every time you run the script) and you don't actually require your testers to do it since you can run remotely from ALM... and if machines are left on, you can run it overnight when nobody is using the machines... again, just need to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand your pain because my projects also need to interact with IE download bar. Usually, I use `SendKeys` to handle download activity in different projects.

When download bar comes out, you can send `ALT+N` first to set focus on download bar, then send some tab keys to select on `Save`, and some `Down Arrow` key to select `SaveAs`.

In this way, you don't need to bother handle UFT notifications...

Sample `SendKeys` codes can be easily Googled.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is also a good solution and I will try it in case my current solution won't get accepted by my team. I actually tried something similar, by clicking on the bar to get focus before adding some Send Keys, but it didn't work and that's when I moved to the current approach (close UFT notification). I didn't know about `ALT+N` until now. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @VictorMoraes As you mentioned, " by clicking on the bar to get focus before adding some Send Keys". Maybe you can try to click a blank area on the webpage to set focus on current page, then send some keys like `Tab` to select `SaveAs`. Actually my solution here has a drawback that the test user should not move mouse or touch keyboard during test runs. Also, sometimes, after `ALT+N` which will set focus on the download bar, the browser may lose focus. Therefore, you need to add a checkpoint, for example, check whether download successfully, if not, use a `Do...While` loop to repeat those thing

Answer (score 0):

Can you activate the desired browser with the following, and then try to do Save as

```
hwnd = Browser("title:=.*").GetROProperty("hwnd")
Window("hwnd:=" & hwnd).Activate
```

Comment: I tried adding this two lines of code before the **If** part but it didn't work. And I guess Activating the browser won't work at all, because the notification tooltip is forced on the top and it seems this operation is performed using the mouse pointer. Looks like I'll have to figure a way to close this tooltip